# Assuming the Goldbach conjectures are true, will all $O$ and $O ⋅ 2$ share at least $1$ of the $p$'s in such a way that the remaining are also $p$'s?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

Assuming the Even Goldbach conjecture is true, it will mean that every even number greater than $2$ as $E$ can be represented as the sum of $2$ primes as $p$'s

Assuming the Odd Goldbach conjecture is true, it will mean that every odd number greater than $7$ as $O$ can be represented as the sum of $3$ primes as $p$'s

Combining all the possibilities, will all $O$ 's and $O ⋅ 2$ 's share at least $1$ of the $p$'s in such a way that the remaining are also $p$'s ? Will there be a way to prove it?

Examples:

$7 = 3 + 2 + 2$ and $14 = 3 + 11$ ($3$ in both)

$9 = 2 + 2 + 5$ and $18 = 13 + 5$ ($5$ in both)

$11 = 5 + 3 + 3$ and $22 = 3 + 19$ ($3$ in both)

$13 = 7 + 3 + 3$ and $26 = 7 + 19$ ($7$ in both)

$15 = 2 + 2 + 11$ and $30 = 11 + 19$ ($11$ in both)

$17 = 7 + 5 + 5$ and $34 = 5 + 29$ ($5$ in both)

$19 = 7 + 7 + 5$ and $38 = 31 + 7$ ($7$ in both)

$21 = 11 + 5 + 5$ and $42 = 11 + 31$ ($11$ in both)

$23 = 5 + 5 + 13$ and $46 = 41 + 5$ ($5$ in both)

$29 = 5 + 5 + 19$ and $58 = 53 + 5$ ($5$ in both)

Comment: For an easy proof we need to assume that every even number $E\ge 8$ is a sum of two *different* primes. This is slightly (?) stronger than Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: Note that the odd Goldbach conjecture has been proved true. When $O$ is large, there will be a tremendous number of sum-of-three-primes representations for $O$, and conjecturally still a very large number of sum-of-two-primes representations for $2O$; so it would be shocking if this ever turned out to be impossible.

Comment: @GregMartin It would also be "shocking" if Goldbach's conjecture turned out to be false. The point is that the author wants to PROVE this conjecture only assuming the strong Goldbach conjecture.

Comment: @ajotatxe I do not expect that we can show that the strong Goldbach conjecture implies that every even number $8$ or larger is the sum of two distinct primes, but I do not think that this strengthening makes a significant difference. If someone will prove Goldbach, I guess this sligtly stronger version would be covered.

Comment: @GregMartin Strong Goldbach is Weak Goldbach but with one of the three primes being 3 ...